# Visualizing LDA topic models using Stephen Hansen's topicmodels package

Tags: python, lda, topic-modeling

I'm using [Stephen Hansen's topicmodels package](https://github.com/sekhansen/text-mining-tutorial) to create a topic model. I'm using the tutorial data available at that link to start. This tutorial uses Python 2 but only requires one changes xrange() to range() in order to have it work properly with Python 3. I was able to run through the tutorial fully but I'm struggling to visually represent the results. First, does anyone have and resources on visualizing LDA models using this package? I haven't been able to locate any.

Primarily, I'm trying to create two kinds of graphics. First, I'm trying to create a word cloud by topic. The second is something that looks like this: (full paper available [here](https://sekhansen.github.io/pdf_files/qje_2018.pdf))

[image: example image]

I have a CSV document from running the tutorial that has all the necessary information to do this that looks like the following:
[image]

The issue is that I'm unsure how to go about creating this document. I'm also unsure how I could use this to create word clouds by topic. There's not much use of topicmodels in python and I don't have very much experience creating any graphics with Python. I'm lost trying to figure out how to convert my output to something I can use with wordclouds or any other visual.

If anyone wants to replicate this data, you just need to have a C++ compiler installed on your computer, download and adjust xrange() in the tutorial, and run it through.